# compiling mod_wsgi in windows 8 is not working intending for django

Tags: python, c++, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am having a LOT of trouble to start with these are my specs

```
windows 8
64 bit
python 2.7
Apachehaus 2.4.12
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to compile mod_wsgi to make the necessary mod_wsgi.so file from the source code.
https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases

I'm trying to compile the ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk and after opening Visual C++ 2008 64-bit command prompt

```
c:\mod_wsgi-4.4.13> nmake -f ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk
c:\mod_wsgi-4.4.13\src\server\wsgi_python.h(24) : fatal error 1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory wsgi_restrict.c
c:\mod_wsgi-4.4.13\src\server\wsgi_python.h(24) : fatal error  1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory wsgi_server.c
c:\python27\mod_wsgi-4.4.13\src\server\wsgi_python.h(24) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory wsgi_stream.c
c:\mod_wsgi-4.4.13\src\server\wsgi_python.h(24) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory wsgi_validate.c
c:\mod_wsgi-4.4.13\src\server\wsgi_python.h(24) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Python.h': No such file or directory
Generating Code...
c:\mod_wsgi-4.4.13\src\server\wsgi_memory.c(124) : warning C4711: function 'getPeakRSS' selected for automatic inline expansion
c:\mod_wsgi-4.4.13\src\server\wsgi_memory.c(125) : warning C4711: function 'getCurrentRSS' selected for automatic inline expansion 
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I already set my path to path=%path% Python27/include because that's where the Python.h file is.

I've also tried

```
python setup install
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "setup.py", line 139, in <module>
        'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't use the `PATH` environment variable for finding header files.  Usually it uses `INCLUDE`.

I think you can pass this into nmake, like so

`nmake INCLUDE=pathToPythonHeader -f ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk`

Comment: Really I give it a try today

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to compile it from source code? Why aren't you using the precompiled binaries?

There is nothing additional in the latter release that you would really need on Windows, so just grab and use the latest binary version which at this time is 4.4.12.

You also can't do a 'python setup.py install' nor a 'pip install' on Windows.

If you really do for some unknown reason need to build from source code, you do at least need to modify the `ap24py27-win64-VC9.mk` file and override the locations for where Python and Apache is installed. The default locations are based on a non standard layout that allows me to have many different Python and Apache versions installed for different architectures at the same time.

Comment: There are no binaries for the build I need. Unless you can find one

Comment: Did you read the README file https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/blob/develop/win32/README.rst and what it said. It is technically not possible to get an entirely compatible set of object binaries for what you want. If you choose to ignore that and try anyway, it says to use ``Apache24-win64-VC10/modules/mod_wsgi-py27-VC9.so`` from the tar ball of binaries available. What are you expecting if this is not it?